# subdomains pointing subfolders with mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

Hi I'm quite new to PHP... And need something to do as fast as I can..

I have some clients within the "clients" directory like here...
**"http://domain.com/clients/client0001/fluids/..."**

I want this URL to be shown in the address bar like this.

**"http://client0001.domain.com/fluids/..."**

with the help of .htaccess. Any help will be appreciated ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite such URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^clients/ clients/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But your webserver needs to be configured so that it accepts such host names and sends the requests to the proper virtual host.

Comment: I'm using Mediatemple's grid service hosting. 
I 've tried to remove www prefix and it worked. 
Does that mean above code will work or not, Gumbo ..

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before as posted by Gumbo.

Only issue I've had with it is that you can't then use further rewrite rules - so if the site you are serving on the subdomain uses url rewriting, you have to make it its own virtual host.